# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

SPARK_VERSION = '3.1.2'.

SCALA_VERSION = '2.12'.

```
import findspark

findspark.add_packages(['org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_' + SCALA_VERSION + ':' + SPARK_VERSION ])
findspark.init()
 
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import sys
import time
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)


/tmp/ipykernel_567977/2450515063.py in <module>
      4 from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
      5 from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
----> 6 from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `KafkaUtils` package belongs to the legacy [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html), while you're trying [Kafka support in Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

Really, there should be no reason to use legacy Spark Streaming in 2023rd.  Just access data in Kafka as described in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).

```py
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port") \
  .option("subscribe", "my_topic") \
  .load()
```